# How to access nested interface types

Tags: typescript, interface, nested

I have an interface that has a second interface as a value as below. But when I try to access the nested values, I get an error. What is the correct way to access nested interface values?

```
interface Results {
    pass: number;
    fail: number;
}

interface Build {
    name: string;
    results: Results;
}

var obj: Build = {
    name: "test",
    results: {
        pass: 3,
        fail: 2
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm trying to access it like so with no luck:

```
obj.results.pass
```

Error I'm getting: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'pass' of undefined

Comment: Should it be `results: Results` rather than `results: Item`?

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: You are correct, @ExplosionPills

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'pass' of undefined @Dethariel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those looking at this later, I had to create a Result object inside of obj such as:

```
this.build["results"] = { pass: 0, fail: 0};
```

Then was able to access and change pass and fail by accessing them like this:

```
this.build["results"].pass = #
this.build["results"].fail = #
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you have is a runtime error (JavaScript execution engine), not a compilation one (TypeScript compiler).

This occurs because you have `obj.results` equal to `undefined`:

```
const test: Build = {};
test.results.pass; // ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'pass' of undefined
```

I would recommend that you check `results` property value before accessing its child property:

```
if (test.results) {
  test.results.pass;
}
```

Comment: I believe you are correct. How would I give the results property itself a value first, since it only has attributes?